# how to get boolean value outside of loop

Tags: java, jframe

I am not sure how to obtain the Boolean value outside of a loop. I checked different websites to which they have suggested that I try to break the loop inside the 'if' statement to which the correct value is supposed to be returned. Unfortunately, those did not work.
Thank you.

The main problematic code:

```
/**
 * Figures out if a game is currently running..
 * @return
 * @throws IOException 
 */
private boolean isGame() throws IOException {
    boolean gameRunning = false;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist");
    // Reads all the current processes running.
    BufferedReader readTasks = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    // CURRENT PROBLEM; IT DOESN'T RETURN CORRECT VALUE AND IDK HOW TO FIX IT.

    // Read through all tasks and see which one is running the game.
    boolean tasksAvaliable = readTasks.ready();
    while (tasksAvaliable) {
        String task = readTasks.readLine();
        if (task.startsWith("svchost.exe")) {
            gameRunning = true;
            return gameRunning;
            //System.out.println("You're good to go.");
            //tasksAvaliable = false;
        } else {
            tasksAvaliable = readTasks.ready();
        }
    }
    return gameRunning;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a help forum***.   Please reduce the code to a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue and specify ***clearly*** what is not working.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: ^^ This is too much code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the problem is with calling `ready()`. JavaDoc: Tells whether this stream is ready to be read.

The problem is, that `ready` may return `false` although there might be further data to read in the future.
You should just write an endless loop and break if `readLine` returns null:

```
for (;;) {
    String task = readTasks.readLine();
    if (task == null) {
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the command tasklist to response.

```
/**
         * Figures out if a game is currently running..
         * @return
         * @throws IOException 
         */
        private boolean isGame() throws IOException {
            boolean gameRunning = false;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist");

            // Reads all the current processes running.
            BufferedReader readTasks = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            // CURRENT PROBLEM; IT DOESN'T RETURN CORRECT VALUE AND IDK HOW TO FIX IT.

            // Read through all tasks and see which one is running the game.
            String task;
            while ((task = readTasks.readLine()) != null) {
                if (task.startsWith("svchost.exe")) {
                    gameRunning = true;
                    return gameRunning;
                    //System.out.println("You're good to go.");
                }
            }
            return gameRunning;
        }
```

Comment: Please note: in that code, there is no point in having that variable. You do a return true first, and the final then goes return false. Having that extra variable doesnt add any value to the code